# Java Concurrent Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locks

Hi I have a paint method that is drawing an image and I have another method that is constantly modifying the image to be drawn however I experience concurrency exceptions now and again. What is the most efficient way to resolve this please? I know I could use synchronized blocks on the buffered image but then it throws up warnings on synchronizing a none final variable.

```
private BufferedImage img;

public void modImage(BufferedImage image) { 
     img = image;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (img != null) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could alternate between two different buffers. One for rendering and one for editing.

Comment: Sorry could you give an example of how to achieve this using buffers

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with synchronizing on a non-final variable. You might have your warning level set unnecessarily high.

Comment: @immibis: There's plenty wrong with it if it's `synchronized (img)`, which is what "use synchronized blocks on the buffered image" sounds like.

Comment: @user2357112 Sure, there are potential bugs that involve `synchronized` and non-final variables, but IMO the signal-to-noise ratio of that warning is way too low. (Why not a "calling method on non-final variable" warning?)

Comment: How is `modImage` being called? Are you reusing the same `BufferedImage` instance each time? or modifying the image after calling `modImage`.

Comment: Synchronization on img witch creates the warning is no good idea since
synchronization on a changing monitors lead to the same unexpected behaviour as the data race it is meant to prevent. By the way synchronization on null will lead to an exception. So the best is to sync on instance as in one of the answers below

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition because the value of `img` can changed in another thread between the `if` conditional and the use of `img` in `drawImage`

```
if (img != null) {                     // <-- img can be non-null here
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);      // <-- img can now be null
}
```

You can assign `img` to a local variable, then use the local variable in-place of `img` in the above code.  The local variable will remain constant even if `img` is changed to a different object in another thread

```
final BufferedImage localImg = img;      // <-- localImg won't change locally
if (localImg != null) {
    g.drawImage(localImg, 0, 0, this);
}
```

In addition to this, `img` should be declared as `volatile` so its value is not cached thread-locally; changes in one thread will be seen by others.

```
private volatile BufferedImage img;
```

Bear in mind that declaring a variable as `volatile` will cause synchronization to occur whenever that variable is accessed; so synchronization *is* still happening.  However, synchronization occurs on the `img` reference itself, not the `BufferedImage` object to which it refers, so there are no issues here if `img` is `null`.

Comment: Without synchronization, there's no guarantee the thread reading `img` will see the other thread's writes.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point!  `img` would need to be declared as volatile.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could sync on instance,

```
private BufferedImage img;

public void modImage(BufferedImage image) { 
     synchronized(this){
         img = image;
     }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    synchronized(this){
    if (img != null) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread-safety issue because the contents of the `BufferedImage` can be changed while the `paintComponent` method is running. Synchronization and volatile in the ui class alone won't fix this.

If you want to add synchronization, then you'll need to make sure any modification of the image is synchronized as well. This needs to be synchronized on some object that's shared between each class involved.

You can avoid some synchronization by making sure to set `img` to a copy of the `BufferedImage` or a different instance each time. It should still be volatile though, and check pathfinderelite's answer if you want to safely set `img` back to `null`.